# Why did Thor summon Stormbreaker during his battle with Thanos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, as Thor was losing in his fight with Thanos we see Thor summon Stormbreaker, which Thanos then catches and uses to try and impale him.

He does a similar feat in *Thor: The Dark World* when fighting Kurse who swats Mjolnir away.

We know from Odin that the weapon was never his source of strength so **why summon it when it could not help?**

Comment: I want to add that I did think that he wanted to use the weapon both time to attack his opponent with their backs turned but I didnt seem too likely.

Comment: So he could whack Thanos with it.

Comment: I might write up a better answer, but that's why you'd grab at any weapon in a fight, so you could use it *as a weapon*

Comment: We also see that while not source of his power it can give him strength... e.g. in the first Thor after he is weakened by the Destroyer and in Infinity War after taking the full force of a star holding the newly forged Strom Breaker helps revive him.

Answer (score 2):

The [screenplay](https://disneystudiosawards.s3.amazonaws.com/avengers-endgame/Avengers_Endgame.pdf) doesn't really give us Thor's *intentions*, but I think we can be pretty sure that his plan (after summoning Stormbreaker) was to use it as a weapon against Thanos.

Note that the bolded stage direction indicates that Thor was having his arse handed to him at the time and may have been a little desperate or not thinking all that clearly.

> Thor attacks, but **Thanos drives him through walls of debris.**
>
> **THANOS SMASHES HIS FIST INTO THOR’S FACE, OVER AND OVER.**
>
> Thor calls for Stormbreaker, but Thanos intercepts it. He presses the
>   blade into Thor’s chest, trying to drive it home.
>
> Then, across the field...MJOLNIR RISES INTO THE AIR.